# Menu dinâmico utilizando AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Tenho uma aplicação que possui um menu no topo e outro na lateral esquerda. 
Os itens do menu deverão ser preenchidos com dados do BD de acordo com perfil de acesso. Porém, o menu não está sendo renderizado quando há mudança de rota.

**Shell.js:**

```
<section>
 <div data-ng-include="'app/controllers/layout/header.html'"></div>
 <div id="menuDin" data-ng-include="'app/autenticado/menuDinamico.html'"></div>
    <div id="corpo" ng-view=""></div>
 <div data-ng-include="'app/controllers/layout/footer.html'"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode disponibilizar um objeto com os itens de seu menu pelo seu controller e depois usar o ng-repeat para desenhar o menu.

```
class MyCtrl
    constructor: ->
        @itens_menu = [ 
            {label: 'Menu1', href: 'url1'}, 
            {label: 'Menu2', href: 'url2'}
        ]


<ul ng-controller="MyCtrl as myctrl">
        <li ng-repeat="item in myctrl.itens_menu">
            <a href="{{item.href}}">{{item.label}}</a>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: A mesma classe acima em javascript seria mais ou menos assim

var MyCtrl;

MyCtrl = (function() {

  MyCtrl.name = 'MyCtrl';

  function MyCtrl() {
    this.itens_menu = [
      {
        label: 'Menu1',
        href: 'url1'
      }, {
        label: 'Menu2',
        href: 'url2'
      }
    ];
  }

  return MyCtrl;

})();